# How to count the number of rows of a JTable?

Tags: swing, jtable

There is a `JTable`. I want to know the number of rows of it. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **[`getRowCount()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getRowCount())** method:

> Returns the number of rows that can be shown in the `JTable`, given
>   unlimited space. If a `RowSorter` with a filter has been specified,
>   the number of rows returned may differ from that of the underlying
>   `TableModel`.

[Here](http://[http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/GettingtheNumberofRowsandColumnsinaJTableComponent.htm) you have one example:

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    Object[][] cellData = { { "1-1", "1-2" }, { "2-1", "2-2" } };
    String[] columnNames = { "col1", "col2" };

    JTable table = new JTable(cellData, columnNames);

    int rows = table.getRowCount();
    int cols = table.getColumnCount();

    System.out.println(rows);
    System.out.println(cols);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 DefaultTableModel t=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
             int number_of_rows = t.getRowCount();
```

note : if empty rows number_of_rows=0